# ExtJS - passing external parameter into Grid renderer

Tags: parameters, extjs, grid, renderer

is there a way to pass external parameter into Grid renderer function?

For example, considering..

```
function excelRenderer(value, p,record){
  return String.format('<a href="excel.jsp?view=aging&prod_type={0}&value={1}" target="_blank"><img src="images/excel.png" border="0"/></a>',record.data.prod_type,value);
} 

function newtab(status){
//add tab
  tabs.add({ 
  ...
  items: new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                region:'center',
                frame: true,
                title: 'testing',
                store: new Ext.data.Store({
                    ...
                }),
                columns: [
                {header: "Column 2", dataIndex: 'col2', sortable: true, renderer: excelRenderer},
                {header: "Column 1", dataIndex: 'col1', sortable: true, renderer: excelRenderer}
                ]
            }
}
```

now I want to add external parameter `status` into the renderer so that the URL rendered will look like

`excel.jsp?view=aging&prod_type=data&value=testing`**&status=pending**

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the renderer function definition inside the `newTab()` function body:

```
function newtab(status){
    var excelRenderer = function(value, p,record){
        return String.format('<a href="excel.jsp?view=aging&prod_type={0}&value={1}&status={2}" target="_blank"><img src="images/excel.png" border="0"/></a>',record.data.prod_type,value, status);
    } 

    //add tab
    tabs.add({ 
        ...
        items: new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
            region:'center',
            frame: true,
            title: 'testing',
            store: new Ext.data.Store({
                ...
            }),
            columns: [
                {header: "Column 2", dataIndex: 'col2', sortable: true, renderer: excelRenderer},
                {header: "Column 1", dataIndex: 'col1', sortable: true, renderer: excelRenderer}
            ]
        }
    });
}
```

There are some other ways (e.g. creating a function callback to `excelRenderer` that's being bound to a supplemental parameter `status`), but this seems to be the easiest way.

**EDIT** (second option using bound parameters):

```
var excelRenderer = function(v, m, r, ri, ci, s, status){
    return String.format('<a href="excel.jsp?view=aging&prod_type={0}&value={1}&status={2}" target="_blank"><img src="images/excel.png" border="0"/></a>',r.data.prod_type, v,  status);
} 

function newtab(status){
    var statusExcelRenderer = excelRenderer.createDelegate(null, [ status ], true);

    //add tab
    tabs.add({ 
        ...
        items: new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
            region:'center',
            frame: true,
            title: 'testing',
            store: new Ext.data.Store({
                ...
            }),
            columns: [
                { header: "Column 2", dataIndex: 'col2', sortable: true, renderer: statusExcelRenderer },
                { header: "Column 1", dataIndex: 'col1', sortable: true, renderer: statusExcelRenderer }
            ]
        }
    });
}
```